# How to get Google Calender API access token using refresh token in Apex Salesforce

Tags: apex, google-apps

Help needed. I am trying to connect to Google Calendar API using refresh token. What I am doing is, I am trying to create event in my google Calendar using refresh token. Code is working for authorization code but not working for refresh token. The Problem is with createOneMore() function. Below is the code of my controller apex class

```
public class NewConnectCalender {
private final string googleClientID = '*****585167-19uflkvq******107628iad29gqan.apps.googleusercontent.com';
private final string googleSecretCode = 'vKp*********Z1hOSiq0Bo';
private final string redirectURI = 'https://***.visual.force.com/apex/VisualForceCalender';
private string authorizationCode = '';
private string state = '';
private string accessToken;
private string refreshToken;
private string expiresIn;
private string tokenType;
String userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
public pageReference doGoogleConnectCall(){


    PageReference pr = new PageReference('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth' +
        '?response_type=code' +
        '&client_id=' + googleClientID +
        '&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI +
        '&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar' +
        '&state=' + 'vcalender ' +
        '&access_type=offline' +
        '&approval_prompt=force' +  //auto, force
        '&login_hint=xxxx@gmail.com');
        System.debug(pr);
    return pr;
}

public void createOneMore(){
    accessToken = null;
    if (refreshToken!=null )
    {
        accessToken = '';
        retrieveGoogleAccessToken1();   
    }
    authorizationCode = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('code');
    if(authorizationCode != null){
        state = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('state');
        accessToken = '';
        retrieveGoogleAccessToken();
        if(accessToken <> ''){
            addCalendarEntry();
        }               
    }
}
public void CalenderConnect(){
    authorizationCode = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('code');
    if(authorizationCode != null){
        state = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('state');
        accessToken = '';
        retrieveGoogleAccessToken();
        if(accessToken <> ''){
            addCalendarEntry();
        }               
    }
}
public void retrieveGoogleAccessToken1(){
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    string endPointValue = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';   
    req.setEndpoint(endPointValue);

    string bodyRequest = '';

    bodyRequest = 'client_id=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(googleClientID, 'UTF-8');
    bodyRequest += '&client_secret=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(googleSecretCode, 'UTF-8');
    bodyRequest += '&refresh_token=' + refreshToken;
    bodyRequest += '&grant_type=refresh_token';

    req.setBody(bodyRequest);         
    req.setHeader('Content-length', string.ValueOf(bodyRequest.length())); 
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setTimeout(10000);
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);   
    map<string, string> jsonValues = new map<string, string>();

    System.debug('Response Value:'+res.getBody());
    jsonValues = parseJSONToMap(res.getBody());
    if(jsonValues.containsKey('error')){ 
    }else{
        //Try to get a cell value in the Google Spreadsheet
        accessToken = jsonValues.get('access_token');
        //refreshToken = jsonValues.get('refresh_token');
        //expiresIn = jsonValues.get('expires_in');
        //tokenType = jsonValues.get('token_type'); 

    }     
}
public void retrieveGoogleAccessToken(){
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    string endPointValue = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';   
    req.setEndpoint(endPointValue);

    string bodyRequest = '';
    bodyRequest = 'code=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(authorizationCode, 'UTF-8');
    bodyRequest += '&client_id=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(googleClientID, 'UTF-8');
    bodyRequest += '&client_secret=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(googleSecretCode, 'UTF-8');
    bodyRequest += '&redirect_uri=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(redirectURI, 'UTF-8');
    bodyRequest += '&grant_type=authorization_code';
    req.setBody(bodyRequest);         
    req.setHeader('Content-length', string.ValueOf(bodyRequest.length())); 
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setTimeout(10000);
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);   
    map<string, string> jsonValues = new map<string, string>();

    System.debug('Response Value:'+res.getBody());
    jsonValues = parseJSONToMap(res.getBody());
    if(jsonValues.containsKey('error')){ 
    }else{
        //Try to get a cell value in the Google Spreadsheet
        accessToken = jsonValues.get('access_token');
        refreshToken = jsonValues.get('refresh_token');
        expiresIn = jsonValues.get('expires_in');
        tokenType = jsonValues.get('token_type'); 

    }     
}
  private void addCalendarEntry(){
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    string endPointValue = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events';
    //This end point does seem to work, but it is not creating an event, just creating a new calendar
    //endPointValue = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars?key=' + googleClientID;
    req.setEndpoint(endPointValue);   
    string bodyRequest = '';
    bodyRequest = '{';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"summary": "Sales Call",';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"location": "Conference Room A",';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"start": {';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"dateTime": "2017-02-12T08:00:00.000-07:00",';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '},';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"end": {';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"dateTime": "2017-02-12T08:30:00.000-07:00",';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '},';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"recurrence": [';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20131226T000000Z"';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '],';       
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"attendees": [';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '{';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '"email": "Tan****ad@gr**ath.com"';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += '}';
    bodyRequest += '\r\n';
    bodyRequest += ']';
    bodyRequest += '}';

    req.setBody(bodyRequest);     
    System.debug(bodyRequest);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    req.setHeader('Content-length', string.ValueOf(bodyRequest.length())); 
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setTimeout(10000);
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
    System.debug(res.getBody());
}

private map<string, string> parseJSONToMap(string JSONValue){
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(JSONValue);
    map<string, string> jsonMap = new map<string, string>();
    string keyValue = '';
    string tempValue = '';
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME){
            keyValue = parser.getText();
            parser.nextToken();
            tempValue = parser.getText();
            jsonMap.put(keyValue, tempValue);             
        }
    }
    return jsonMap;
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your retrieveGoogleAccessToken1() function.

When requested access token by using refresh token the ENDPOINT URL should be **accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token** instead of **accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth**

Below are debugs using both ENDPOINTS.

1. Using Auth[image]
2. Using Token[image]

Let me know if this solves your issue.